# Selection of columns in a modelChoiceField queryset: output messed up

Tags: django, select, field, django-queryset, choicefield

I have a modelChoiceField created with Django:

```
lawsToValidate=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=LawsIdsModel.objects.filter(validated=0).values("releveAnnee", "releveMois", "noOrdre"), widget=forms.Select(attrs={'onchange': 'javascript: lawToValidateDisplay(this.value);'}))
```

The django code creates this html code:

```
<option value="{'releveMois': 1L, 'noOrdre': 2L, 'releveAnnee': 2009L}">{'releveMois': 1L, 'noOrdre': 2L, 'releveAnnee': 2009L}</option>
```

The django code calls my jquery function right after the click on the drop down list. If I display the selected value in my javascript function, here is what I have:

```
{'releveMois': 1L, 'noOrdre': 3L, 'releveAnnee': 2009L}
```

How do I get the information from this python dictionnary in jquery / javascript. How do I get releveMois, releveAnnee, noOrdre? If I try jQuery.parseJSON, it does not work!

**EDIT:** 
With the comments below, I understood that it was better to change the html output. Here is my template code to generate the drop down list:

```
<div id="lawsToValidateChoice" class="fieldWrapper">
            {{ form.lawsToValidate.errors }}
            <select  onchange="javascript: lawToValidateDisplay(this.value);" name="lawsToValidate" id="id_lawsToValidate">
                <option value="" selected="selected">Select a law to validate</option>
                {% for law in form.lawsToValidate.field.queryset %}
                    <option value="{{ law.releveAnnee }},{{ law.releveMois }},{{ law.noOrdre }}">releveAnnee={{ law.releveAnnee }}, releveMois={{ law.releveMois }}, noOrdre={{ law.noOrdre }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
```

No problem anymore to parse the values! Solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way to solve that...
The problem is : when selecting a few columns with `values` in a `queryset`, it messes the output. The solution was to use `only` instead (before the filter).

```
lawsToValidate=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=LawsIdsModel.objects.only("releveAnnee", "releveMois", "noOrdre").filter(validated=0), widget=forms.Select(attrs={'onchange': 'javascript: lawToValidateDisplay(this.value);'}))
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [`json` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) to serialize your results, not the `str` conversion of your dictionary.

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(result), mimetype="application/json")
```

Better still, use a [`JSONResponse()` object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) or a  [Django serializer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/serialization/) to create the JSON result for you; the first is a full replacement for the `HttpResponse` object that encodes to JSON, and ensures the correct mimetype is used.

Comment: In my modelChoiceField, I have: widget=forms.Select(attrs={'onchange': 'javascript: lawToValidateDisplay(this.value);'}). The javascript function is called right after the click on the drop down list. Do I have to change that to apply your code or is there an other way?

Comment: @rom: that's the JavaScript side, what I posted is what the *server* (python code) produces. Are you saying your html `select` values are what you posted in your question?

Comment: yes exactly! I think I should change that cause it's quite ugly. I just don't know how to do and thought it would not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

First create a JSON at server side (e.g. using `json` module):

```
import json
json = json.dumps(queryset)
```

Then parse retrieved JSON in JavaScript with `parseJSON()` (or `JSON.parse` for modern browsers):

```
var json = $.parseJSON(jsonVar);
console.log(json.releveMois);
```

Comment: In my modelChoiceField, I have: widget=forms.Select(attrs={'onchange': 'javascript: lawToValidateDisplay(this.value);'}). The javascript function is called right after the click on the drop down list. Do I have to change that to apply your code or is there an other way?